# Premiere Pro Extendscript checkbox selection in MOGRT

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript, adobe-premiere

When coding a Premiere Pro Panel in Adobe Extendscript I can import a MOGRT file and set the value for sliders using the below code:

`var transition = app.project.activeSequence.importMGTFromLibrary("WARATAH TV", "WARATAH TV 2019-20 TRANSITION", (myStartTime - 0.55), 2, 2);`

`transition.setSelected(true);`

`var components = transition.getMGTComponent();`

`components.properties.getParamForDisplayName("Slider Value").setValue(5);`

**However, when I try to check/uncheck a checkbox value in the MOGRT after import, the same bit of code does not work????**

`components.properties.getParamForDisplayName("Checkbox Value").setValue(false);`

Any ideas as to why or how to change the value of the check boxes???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing the second parameter 'boolUpdateUI'...

```
setValue componentParam.setValue(newValue, boolUpdateUI)

Description

Obtains the value of the component parameter stream. Note: This can only work on parameters which are not time-variant.

Parameters

The newValue must be of the appropriate type for the component parameter stream; passing 1 for boolUpdateUI will force Premiere Pro to update its UI, after updating the value of the stream.

Returns

Returns 0 if successful.
```